# Why does multiplying a character produce other seemingly random characters?

Tags: c, printf

I can't understand why this code output is weird. I wrote this out of curiosity and now if I enter 55 it shows a leaf. And also many other things depending on number. I searched it in google but didn't find any possible explanation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char input='*';
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("%c",input*x);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Characters are encoded as integers, usually 8-bit by default in C.  Some are defined by [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and others depend on your OS, screen font, etc.

The `*` character has code 42.  If you enter 55, your code computes 42*55=2310 and uses the low 8 bits of this value, which is 6, as the character to print.  Character 6 is ACK which is not defined as a printable character by ASCII, but it sounds like your system is using something like the legacy [IBM code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), in which character 6 displays as the spade symbol ♠.

Multiplying a character code by an integer is not a very useful thing to do.  I'm not sure what you were expecting to accomplish with this program.  If you thought it would print 55 copies of the `*` character, like Perl's `x` operator, well it doesn't.  C has no built-in way to do that; you would just write a loop that prints `*` once per iteration, and iterates 55 times.